# Remove a CSS class from HTML element in the code behind file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following on my interface / webform:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="forceHeight" runat="server" />
```

Now I have a condition in my code behind where if a certain situation is true I need to remove the `forceHeight` class from this control. I know in C# you can use:

```
mydiv.CssClass.Replace("forceHeight", "");
```

I'm not so sure how you do this using VB? Intellisense doesn't offer me this option?

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: The answer from @Obsidian should really be the accepted answer here. The currently accepted answer just removes all classes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will remove all CSS classes from the div with `ID="mydiv"`

```
Me.mydiv.Attributes("class") = ""
```

Answer (score 35):

### How to remove ONE CSS class from a control using .NET

If a control has several classes you can remove **one** of those classes by editing the class string. Both of these methods require assigning an ID to the HTML element so that you can target it in the code behind.

```
<asp:Panel ID="mydiv" CssClass="forceHeight class2 class3" runat="server" />
```

**VB.NET**

```
mydiv.CssClass = mydiv.CssClass.Replace("forceHeight", "").Trim()
```

**C#**

```
mydiv.CssClass = mydiv.CssClass.Replace("forceHeight", "").Trim();
```

---

**OR** using *html generic control*

```
<div id="mydiv" class="forceHeight class2 class3" runat="server" />
```

**VB.NET**

```
mydiv.Attributes("class") = mydiv.Attributes("class").Replace("forceHeight", "").Trim()
```

**C#**

```
mydiv.Attributes["class"] = mydiv.Attributes["class"].Replace("forceHeight", "").Trim();
```

---

Optional `Trim` to remove trailing white space.

---

### How to remove ALL CSS classes from a control using .NET

**VB.NET**

```
mydiv.Attributes.Remove("class")
```

**C#**

```
mydiv.Attributes.Remove("class");
```

Comment: I'm confused as why OP accepted the answer that is accepted. He seemed to ask how to remove `a single css class` and the above answers give the solution on how to remove `all css classes`. Besides, what he tried was almost what he wanted to do: `mydiv.CssClass.Replace("forceHeight", ""); `. But a lot of people forget that `Replace` is a method that returns a `String` object, and not a procedure, thus you must affect it to a variable.

Comment: Also, may I suggest that you `Trim` the given String like so: `Me.mydiv.CssClass.Replace("forceHeight", "").Trim()`? It makes the html more pleasant to read when there aren't unnecessary spaces in the `class` attribute.

Comment: @BishopBarber You are correct I came across this question but ended up having to solve it myself. I added my findings to help others who came here. P.s Trim added 'cleanliness is happiness =)`

Comment: A div does not have the CssClass property, does it? And instead of also using `Trim()`, you could just include the white space in the replace call.

Comment: @Skillzore A div does have a `class` and this class can be referenced from code behind by calling `CssClass` provided a `runat="server"` tag is present. Additionally using the white space in the call would not work because then the class would only be removed if the white space existed which in some cases it does not.

Comment: @Obsidian Well, on the white space you are correct of course. But in code behind, at least for C#, a div is a `HtmlGenericControl` and `runat="server"` doesn't change that. A `HtmlGenereicControl` does not have a `CssClass` property, at least not according to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). If some other .NET language supports `div.CssClass` please specify so in the answer.

Comment: Replacing a substring may modify other classes (e.g. forceHeight2).  To be certain, the class can be split to array and filtered: 
`mydiv.Attributes["class"] = String.Join(" ", mydiv.Attributes["class"].Split(' ').Where(x => x != "forceHeight"));`

To filter on multiple classes a HashSet contains can be used: 
        `mydiv.Attributes["class"] = String.Join(" ", mydiv.Attributes["class"].Split(' ').Where(x => !(new HashSet<string> { "one", "two" }).Contains(x)));`

Answer (score 11):

```
Me.mydiv.Attributes.Remove("class")
```

is much better since it won't leave a stub behind. It'll produce a cleaner HTML tag.

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

If you use this,

```
Me.mydiv.Attributes("class") = ""
```

it will produce this instead

`<div id="mydiv" class=""></div>` OR `<div id="mydiv" class></div>`

Answer (score 5):

I find it better to use REGEX replace since replacing class could exist as partial name in other classes which would break them. So I'm using the following extension method:

```
public static void RemoveClass(this WebControl control, string classToRemove)
{
    if (control == null)
        return;

    control.CssClass = Regex.Replace(control.CssClass, @"(^|\s)" + classToRemove + @"($|\s)", " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mydiv.Attributes["class"] = mydiv.Attributes["class"].ToString().Replace("ClassName","")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydiv.Attributes("class") = mydiv.Attributes("class").Replace("forceHeight", "")
```

The other answers did not work for me. Like the OP said, I'm not getting `myDiv.CssClass` in `IntelliSense`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void appendCssClass(HtmlGenericControl htmlGenericControl, string cssClassName)
    {
        htmlGenericControl.Attributes.Add("class", 
            htmlGenericControl.Attributes["class"].ToString() + " " + cssClassName);
    }

    public static void removeCssClass(HtmlGenericControl htmlGenericControl, string cssClassName)
    {
        htmlGenericControl.Attributes.Add("class",
                    htmlGenericControl.Attributes["class"].Replace(cssClassName, ""));
    }
```

Comment: This code may indeed answer the question, but without explanation it's not clear how exactly, and how it differs from other answers. Can you please add some comments to make your answer more useful to future readers?