# How to remove CssClass for asp:panel using asp vb .net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I remove CssClass for asp:panel using asp vb.net?
I have been trying with several methods such as:

```
panelOculto.CssClass = panelOculto.CssClass.Replace("hidden", " ").Trim()
```

but it's not working.

```html
<div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: right;padding-right: 0;">
  <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panelOculto" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="hidden" >
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnExcel" OnClick="btnExcel_Click" ImageUrl="~/Recursos/assets/EXCEL-ICON.png" Width="100" Height="70" ClientIDMode="Static" />
  </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to format your question better. Can you show more of the code/data?

Comment: Do any of these solutions help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870679/remove-a-css-class-from-html-element-in-the-code-behind-file

Comment: I'm trying to change the CssClass from Hidden to Visible but for some reason the asp panel never get the  instruction from the server.   This is what I have : if gvReport.rows.count = 0 then panel1.visible = false else panel1.visible = true  .  All this is in a private sub after been calling by onclick event